# Haskell: A stricter fold' with deepseq

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold, seq

The page [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) discusses `foldl'`, and defines it like:

```
foldl' f z []     = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                    in seq z' $ foldl' f z' xs
```

This is done to avoid space leaks, i.e. so `fold'` that produces a constant size result only uses constant space.

However, this doesn't necessarily work, as pointed out here:

> The involved `seq` function does only evaluate the top-most constructor. If the accumulator is a more complex object, then `fold'` will still build up unevaluated thunks.

The obvious solution is to change `seq` to [`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:deepseq) as shown (assuming you're working with [`NFData`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html#t:NFData)):

```
foldl_strict f z []     = z
foldl_strict f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                          in deepseq z' $ foldl_strict f z' xs
```

But I have a feeling this can be horribly inefficient, as the entire structure will need to be traversed by `deepseq` each pass through the loop (unless the compiler can statically prove this is not necessary).

I then tried this:

```
foldl_stricter  f z l      = deepseq z $ foldl_stricter' f z l
foldl_stricter' f z []     = z
foldl_stricter' f z (x:xs) = let z' = deepseq x $ z `f` x 
                             in seq z' $ foldl_stricter' f z' xs
```

But found it had this issue. The below fails when it should return 3.

```
foldl_stricter (\x y -> x + head y) 0 [[1..],[2..]]
```

So `fold_stricter` is too strict. The list need not be strict, what is important to prevent a space leak is that the accumulator is strict. `fold_stricter` goes too far and also makes the list strict also, which causes the above to fail.

Which takes us back to `fold_strict`. Does repeatedly running `deepseq` on a data structure of size `n` take `O(n)` time, or only `O(n)` time the first time and `O(1)` thereafter? (As [dbaupp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256624/dbaupp) suggests in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093922/haskell-a-stricter-fold-with-deepseq#comment14527591_11093922) below)

Comment: As far as I understand, `deepseq` only traverses the structure of its first argument, and doesn't need to re-evaluate expressions. E.g. let `x = 1 + 2` and `y = 3 + x`, then if `x` has been `deepseq`'d, evaluating `deepseq y ..` will only need to traverse to `(+) 3 x`: it won't need to look inside `x` (other than to get the value `3` out of it) because the thunk has already been forced. (Or is that incorrect?)

Comment: @dbaupp: I agree in this case, but what happens if `x` is a large tree of `Int`s. We `deepseq` it, which evaluates all the `Int`s, but we still have a tree of (now evaluated) Ints. When we `deepseq` again, do we have to go through the entire tree again to check these Ints are evalutated, or do we somehow know at the top level that the tree has been `deepseq`ed already?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, your two implementations of `foldl` are significantly different. There is no guarantee that `f z x` will need to completely traverse `x` to compute its answer, so `deepseq x (f z x)` may do unnecessary work; moreover, even if `x` is completely evaluated, there is no guarantee that `f z x` has no nested thunks, so `let z' = deepseq x (f z x) in seq z' (foo z')` may not do enough work.

The correct solution to the problem you stated is to use `foldl'` and a strict data type as the accumulator type; this way, the `seq` will only need to check the constructor to know that the entire structure is completely evaluated, and conversely forcing the constructor will force the entire structure to be completely evaluated.

Comment: Can you give an example of a fold function which does what you says, makes the accumulator strict? Or is there no generic solution to this problem, and instead one must define a new strict accumulator type every time one wants to do such a fold?

Comment: @Clinton You're correct: you must create a distinct strict type for each different type of accumulator you want (or use an existing strict type). This is exactly the same situation you face with lazy folds: each different kind of accumulator must either create a new type or reuse an existing (lazy) type, so I don't consider this much of an objection.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. Can you explain and/or give an example why `foldl_strict` may not do enough work?

Comment: @Clinton `foldl_strict` always does enough work. It is `foldl_stricter` which may not do enough work. Consider, e.g., `f z x = x : x : z`, for which your `seq` only evaluates the first `:` and not the second.

Comment: So is `foldl_strict` the equivalent of defining a strict accumulator type? If not, how is it different?

Comment: @Clinton No, `foldl_strict` is not equivalent: as you observed, the `deepseq` in `foldl_strict` may do a lot of retraversals, whereas a strict data type only triggers a traversal on its first evaluation.

Comment: Is `foldl_strict` functionally equivalent (even though it isn't as efficient) as defining a strict accumulator datatype? If so, how is the strict accumulator datatype "smarter" than `deepseq` i.e. how does it avoid the repeated traversals?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12725/discussion-between-daniel-wagner-and-clinton)